# Is there a way to find out bitbucket team repositories names using git?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have a bitbucket team which has several repositories but I forgot the user password to login. I have the user password credentials for team through which I can access and clone the repo. Is there a way to find out the names or link to repositories in this scenario?
Any API or git command would do. I have searched all way on bitbucket site but could not find any information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test listing repostories with the [REST Browser API](http://restbrowser.bitbucket.org/), entering the credentials that you do have, and testing a:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/user/repositories/
```

Or, in your case, selecting the 2.0 API:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/teams/{teamname}/repositories
```

(replace `{teamname}` by the name of the team)

---

Th [OP Anuj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188193/anuj) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113970/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-bitbucket-team-repositories-names-using-git/24114086?noredirect=1#comment37239164_24114086):

> I made it work by asking the administrator to creating a user for me.
>   By default, the bitbucket team user is disabled.

Comment: @Anuj you did, through the REST Brower API?

Comment: @Anuj and see the comment of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490763/how-to-get-full-list-of-repositories-that-allowed-for-user#comment36444326_23490763

Comment: Yes through rest browser API.

Comment: Thanks for link. Now I am getting 200 OK but No results. I tried giving user, password parameters. The problem is that I know the password of only the team user which is not allowed to login using the bitbucket.

Comment: @Anuj then bitbucket support should able to help, in order to check if the credentials you have give you the right to access or not the information you seek.

Comment: @Anuj did the support gave you an answer? Or were you able to make that query work?

Comment: I made it work by asking the administrator to creating a user for me. By default, the bitbucket team user is disabled.

Comment: @Anuj Excellent. I have added your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the API link btw.

Answer (score 6):

The following cURL command will give all the repositories.

```
curl -s https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/users/{teamname}/ -u {repo_user}:{repo_password}
```